# Laravel and Digital Ocean PostgreSQL Connection Pools

Tags: laravel, postgresql, digital-ocean

I have a PostgreSQL Database Cluster at DigitalOcean.
My Laravel application connects to the database.
But I have some concurrent connection issues, so the solution is to use DigitalOcean "Connection Pool".

I configure it like this:

```
DB_HOST=the-same.db.ondigitalocean.com
DB_PORT=25061 # 25060 is the port for the normale DB-connection
DB_DATABSE=name-of-the-pool # Instead of default DB-name, this is configured via DO
```

But connection is not working when I connect like DO tells me to do.

I get errors like this:

```
SQLSTATE[26000]: Invalid sql statement name: 7 ERROR:  prepared statement "pdo_stmt_00000012" does not exist (SQL: select sum("amount") as aggregate from "stock_mutations" where "stock_mutations"."stockable_type" = App\Models\Product and "stock_mutations"."stockable_id" = 242 and "stock_mutations"."stockable_id" is not null and "created_at" <= 2022-11-17 11:17:31)
```

And when I revert to the default port from DO and the original db-name, it works like it should.

What am I doing wrong or need I do extra for Laravel, to make connection to the Digital Ocean Connection Pools?

Comment: Using prepared statements with a transaction-level connection pool won't work well. Use functions instead.

Comment: That is not something I chose to do ;-) It's all default Laravel Eloquent queries I run. I have no clue what prepared statements are for example.